# how could the http headers and http body in the same reponse message

Tags: python, http

I have no experience on Http, so I'm not sure what caused this.
My service is written in python. The code below is the web server response function.
i use the wireshark to capture,and found that there are two messages send out from the server.
how could the headers and body in the same response message.

code:

```
     '''the bytes of sss is 1024'''
def start_burn(self):
    global allburnerdata
    burnPageNumer = round(len(allburnerdata) / 1024)
    self.send_response(200)
    sss = bytearray();
    sss.append(0xF1);
    sss.append(burnPageNumer);
    self.send_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(sss)))
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(sss) 
    return
```

Comment: What do you mean by "found that there are two messages send out from the service"?  Remember that there is a maximum size for transmitted ethernet frames, so if your response is larger than that value you're going to see multiple packets when sending a single response.

Comment: @larsks i just mean that the http headers and http body are in not in the same packet.is there any way to put http headers and body together and response back.